# Routing in Zend Framework of two modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I have created controller :  module/default/index/login
I have added routing in main bootstrap

```
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action', array(
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'index',

        ));
        $router->addRoute('defaulth', $route);
```

### When i accessing url/login it work fine

After that  I have created another controller : module/user/index/register

When i access url/user/register it return error invalid action

When i access url/user/index/register it works fine.

I have to access with url/user/register

Please suggest any one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the name of the route was voluntary (`defaulth`), but with `default` you'll overwrite ZF's default main routing, which is `:module\:controller\:action\*`.

Try `:controller\:action\*` as the route.